# How do I connect Parity and TestRpc

Tags: parity, testrpc, web3j

My very much appreciated and valued Conor Svensson -who creates web3j- gave me a very simple task so that we can reproduce the issue https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/105#issuecomment-309186331.

"Please can you try running the code using Geth or Parity?" I am new, with all this Etherium stuff and now Conor expects me to do something that I completely fail to understand.

I am puzzled but willing to take the challenge. The problem arises when web3j tries to connect to TestRpc which is "is a Node.js based Ethereum client for testing and development".

Then he wants me to connect with Geth or Parity. I opt for Parity. "Parity's goal is to be the fastest, lightest, and most secure Ethereum client."

So we have two clients that Conor wants me to connect. Please provide me the wisdom to solve Conors puzzle.

Comment: How to connect parity to testrpc, I'd ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parity and Geth are two full Ethereum clients (there are more). They are the backbone of the Ethereum blockchain. They process smart contracts, help transfer ether back and forth between accounts, and are the actual software systems that come to "consensus" every X seconds.

The `testrpc` is a test client. It's a node.js module (program?) that runs locally on your machine. It doesn't have to come to consensus, therefore, its way faster than using a regular node -- instantaneous for all intents and purposes. Plus--importantly--it's working with fake `ether`.

I think what the developer is asking you to do is use a 'real' client in your issue report as opposed to the 'not-real' test net.